# Functions with similar parameter but have different outputs

Tags: c++

I have to write multiple functions that have similar parameters. Is there a way to make it shorter and readable?
Here is an example code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void test1(int index){
    std::cout << "Chosen Answer : " << index << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ABCD ";
}

void test2(int index){
    std::cout << "Chosen Answer : " << index << std::endl;
    std::cout << "JKLM ";
}

void test3(int index){
    std::cout << "Chosen Answer : " << index << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PQRS ";
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> input;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        input.push_back(i);
    }
    
    test1(input[1]);
    test2(input[2]);
    test3(input[3]);
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: sounds like a xy problem

Comment: Is it necessary to use multiple functions? If not you can just combine the three functions into one.

Comment: find out what is same and what is different between them. What is same you put into another function, what is different is parameters to that function.

Comment: Try writing a single function.   In that function, choices for selecting a second output string include (1) use an `if/else` chain to select the second output string based on the argument  (2)   create a `const` and/or `static` container of string, and use the argument as an index into that container (after checking the argument is a valid index).

Comment: @amgroot Why is there 5 answers and only 3 functions?

Comment: @omid yes because inside each of the functions there are different math logic that has to be done depends on the given index and each functions is printing the result of math logic with different paragraph.

Comment: @iamgroot could you be a bit more specific (e.g., about the math logic) or provide some more details about the usage? Otherwise the only thing I can think of is that if you "have to" use different functions you could use some macro coding and simplify the function calls.

Comment: If they differ only by a mathematical formula, one way to go is to have an array with lambda functions and iterate over that one.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you can create a gểnal function that has another parameter that specifies what function do you want to use:

```cpp
void test(int index, int mode)
{
    switch(mode)
    {
        case 1:
            test1();
            break;
        case 2:
            test2();
            break;
        case 3:
            test3();
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Invalid mode ";
            break;
    }
}
// code ...

int main()
{
    test(input, 1) // call test1()
    test(input, 2) // call test2()
    test(input, 3) // call test3()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on a comment, basically it is always the same procedure: find out what is same and what is different between them. What is same you put into another function, what is different is parameters to that function.

What is same:

```
std::cout << "Chosen Answer : " << index << std::endl;
std::cout <<
```

What is different

```
              "some string";
```

Put what is same in a function and what is different is parameters to that function:

```
 void test(int index, const std::string& text) {         
     std::cout << "Chosen Answer : " << index << std::endl;
     std::cout << text;
 }
 void test1(int index) { test(index,"ABCD"); }
 void test2(int index) { test(index,"JKLM"); }
 void test3(int index) { test(index,"PQRS"); }
```

This was refactoring from the functions point of view. If we considered `main`, then perhaps we wouldn't need `test1`,`test2` and `test3` in the first place:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> input;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        input.push_back(i);
    }
    
    std::vector<std::string> texts{"ABCD","JKLM","PQRS"};
    for (int i=0; i<3; ++i) {
        test(input[i+1],texts[i]);
    }
}
```

> yes because inside each of the functions there are different math logic that has to be done depends on the given index and each functions is printing the result of math logic with different paragraph.

Thats not what your code example illustrates, though the procedure is the same: Find the common part, find the parts that are different. You can pass callables to functions to factor out some maths. A simple way to do that is via lambdas, for example:

```
template <typename F>
void calc(F f,int a, int b,const std::string& op) {
    std::cout << a << op << b << "=" << f(a,b) << "\n";
}

int main() {
    calc( [](int a,int b) { return a+b; },1,2,"+");
    calc( [](int a,int b) { return a-b; },1,2,"-");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can declare methods even more shorter.

```
#define DECLARE_TEST_METHOD(name, output_value) void test##name(int index) { \
                                                std::cout << "Chosen Answer : " << index << std::endl; \
                                                std::cout << output_value; \
                                                }
DECLARE_TEST_METHOD(1, "ABCD ");
DECLARE_TEST_METHOD(2, "JKLM ");
DECLARE_TEST_METHOD(3, "PQRS ");
```

Comment: Preprocessor macros without a need for them are a good way to make bug fixing hard later on. In this case, there is zero reason not to use an `inline` function instead at least. Also, this does not help the questioneers task, see their clarification with mathematical functions.